# How to load more images in fallbacks image, next-pwa

Tags: next-pwa

## Versions

- `next-pwa`:
- `next`:

## Question

How to load more images in fallbacks.image
for example i neeed two images into fallbacks

file - next.config.js

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');
module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    fallbacks: {
      image: 'static/fallback.svg'
    },
  }
})
```